# How to declare array of IVector<double>^ Points in C++?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, windows-store-apps, direct2d

One small help in my Direct2D application. I have `IVector<double>^ points` collection in my C++ application. I will set this points collection from my C# code. So i can set `IList<double>` from my C# to the `IVector<double>^` points to get the List of double.

Here is my requirement that, I have to set the collection of `double[]` to the C++ code. In C# we can simply declare the collection with the following syntax `List<double[]>`. But as i am new to C++  , i am not much familiar with the available API in the C++ library in Windows Store apps. Any one can you please help me on this.?. So eventually my requirement is simple in two lines that " I should be able to set the `List<double[]>` to my C++ library from my C# code".

Any help much appreciated.

-David C

Comment: You should clarify that this is C++/CLI (though the knowledgeable parties will pick it up right away). The short of it is yes, you can do what you want to do, there are many ways to do it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what your issue is, since you haven't shown any code at all, but I think you might just be tripping over the array syntax.

In C++/CLI, you can declare an array with square brackets (`double[]`), and that works, but it's an unmanaged array. You can't have that as a field in a managed class, and passing that to managed APIs isn't easy.

The syntax for a managed array is `array<double>`. This is a reference type, so you'll want the `^` when you have a variable of this type.

```
array<double>^ buffer = gcnew array<double>(1024);
```

Therefore, your `List<double[]>` in C# turns into `List<array<double>^>` in C++/CLI.